# Is it possible to create a macro, that will create a hyperlink, that will run a macro

Tags: vba, excel, hyperlink

I'm just wondering if you can create a Macro, that will hyperlink a cell and assign a separate macro to it?

I know you can use a hyperlink to run a macro using the following

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
       Call Macro Name
End Sub
```

I also know you can use a macro to create a Hyperlink using the following

```
With Worksheets(1) 
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("a5"), _ 
 Address:="", _ 
 ScreenTip:="", _ 
 TextToDisplay:= ""
End With
```

Is there anyway to put these together? Or is there a way to use the second code to assign a macro? instead of an address?

So if I made a macro that takes data from a raw data tab, and puts it into a table like this

[image: Table with Hyperlinks]

The macro then needs to assign a hyperlink to the values (4,2,5,2,5) that will run a separate macro when clicked. I'm hoping it would look something like this

```
With Worksheets(1) 
 .Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=.Range("B2"), _ 
 Address:=Macro Name, _ 
 ScreenTip:="", _ 
 TextToDisplay:= ""
End With
```

There is much more to it as the table may have more rows so the hyperlinks will have to have a variable range etc, but i'd just to know if it's possible because I can't get it to work as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but not by default. You will to perform some kind of workaround:

Create a hyperlink on eg cell B2 linking to B2 itself.

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("B2"), Address:="", SubAddress:=Range("B2").Address
```

And then use the `Target` to decide which macro should be called, so you can use the address `Target.Parent.Address` or the cell value `Target.Parent.Value` to distinguish between the macros.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    'decide by address
    Select Case Target.Parent.Address
        Case "$B$2"
            CallMacro1
        Case "$B$3"
            CallMacro1
    End Select

    'or by intersection a range
    Select Case True
        Case Not Intersect(Target.Parent, Range("B4:B8")) Is Nothing
            CallMacro1
    End Select


    'or by value
    Select Case Target.Parent.Value
        Case 2
            CallMacro1
        Case 4
            CallMacro1
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note that the `Call` statement is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Just use the macro name itself to call a macro: Instead of `Call MacroName` just use `MacroName`.

---

Alternatively use the `ScreenTip` as workaround to set the macro name

```
.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("B4"), Address:="", SubAddress:= _
    Range("B4").Address, ScreenTip:="MyMacro"
```

and then use the `ScreenTip` to run that macro

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Run Target.ScreenTip
End Sub
```

Note that the `MyMacro` has to be public in a Module otherwise you need to use eg. `Sheet1.MyMacro` to tell in which scope the macro actually is. Otherwise it will throw an error that the macro name does not exist.

Note also that this is a kind of workaround, that miss-uses the `ScreenTip`.

Comment: Brilliant thank you! I'm getting there with it, just wondering if there's any way to set the Case as a range instead of specifically B4? So could i set the range to B4:B8 and whenever I click a hyperlink within this range it Calls Macro1

Comment: @Dullspark of course you can use `Intersect` to test if the cell intersects with a range. See my edited example

Comment: Final Question. When I set the Hyperlinks using your first piece of code, i then have to delete all rows that contain 0. This messes with the hyperlinks as they don't move with the deleted rows. (e.g. The initial hyperlink goes to B4, If i delete Row 3, the Cell moves up to occupy B3 but the hyperlink stays at B4. Is there any way to counter this?

Comment: @Dullspark No, the only workaround for this is to name the cell and link to the name instead. But not sure if this is a good idea at all. Note I updated the  `Case Intersection` line causing an issue when not intersecting!

Comment: Hi Again, to get around this i've copied the data to a hidden sheet before rows are deleted and I was trying to link hyperlink in the visual sheet to that of the hidden sheet using this `.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range(Cells(P1, P), Cells(P1, P)), Address:="", SubAddress:=Worksheets("Hidden Sheet").Range(Cells(P1, P), Cells(P1, P)).Address` (Where P1 and P are iterations) however it doesn't like this at all! It pulls 'Error 1004 - Application-defined or object-defined error' when i try to run it. Any ideas why?

Comment: Well probably linking to a hidden sheet doesn't make much sense. It cannot jump there if it is hidden.

Comment: Even if I unhide the sheet it still pulls up the same error :(

Comment: Ah to get the address including the worksheet name it should be `.Address(External:=True)` Otherwise please check what the output of that address is.

Comment: Sorry, complete noob when checking what's happening with my code. I'm assuming I do this using the Immediate window?

Comment: Well debugging is absolutely necessary to understand. You cannot code without debugging! But have a look at [Excel Easy - Debugging](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) which explains some basics. For a deeper look into debugging google for some debugging tutorials.

Comment: Thank you! I much appreciate the assistance too!