# Is it possible to use cell hyperlink to run a macro?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm generating lines and changes and want to automate the linking with a macro
However i wish to add the link to the macro in a clickable cell.

I tried using the same way i would link a URL, to get started then i need to figure out if 
i can assign the "SubAddress:="  to a macro instead of a link?

```
ws.Range("H6").Hyperlinks.Add anchor:=ws.Range("H6"), Address:="", SubAddress:="runMACRO", TextToDisplay:="Show tasks"
```

Update SOLVED --

the solution i went with was link my macro as "screentip" then following this to run it ;)

```
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Run target.ScreenTip
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes, you can, but not in that way... A trick must be used. Making a hyperlink for the cell itself and then using the `WorksheetFollowHyperlink` event for the `Target.Parent.Address`. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751600/is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-that-will-create-a-hyperlink-that-will-run-a), please...

Comment: That is very clever ;)   I ended up using
`
Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal target As Hyperlink)
    Application.Run target.ScreenTip
End Sub
`
Drop an answer if you want the points, otherwise i just accept the otherone below.

Comment: OK. I will make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can, but not in that way... A trick must be used. Making a hyperlink for the cell itself and then using the WorksheetFollowHyperlink event for the Target.Parent.Address. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49751600/is-it-possible-to-create-a-macro-that-will-create-a-hyperlink-that-will-run-a), please...

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you can make use of the `Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink` event handler. Hence, you would have to, in the `ThisWorkbook` module, to add something like the following code which would call `runMACRO` whenever a hyperlink in cell `H6` is clicked.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetFollowHyperlink(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    If Target.Range.Address = "$H$6" Then
        Call runMACRO
    End If
End Sub
```